# Why no listoffigures Koma?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\part{Foo}
\chapter{Intro}
\lipsum[66]
\section{Foo}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
         \caption{image-a}
         \label{fig:a}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[66]
\subsection{Bar}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

I only want to display `Parts` in the `tableofcontents`, but this solution doesn't display the `listoffigures`, it does however generate a List of Figures title page. Perhaps there's a separate `setcounter` or modifier for this, or am I missing the obvious in that setting `\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}` precludes the `listoffigures` displaying, if so is there another solution?

Comment: The list of figures and tables are chapters. Not parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change tocdepth before the listoffigures:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\listoffigures
\part{Foo}
\chapter{Intro}
\lipsum[66]
\section{Foo}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
         \caption{image-a}
         \label{fig:a}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[66]
\subsection{Bar}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could use

```
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\value{tocdepth}=\parttocdepth}
```

instead the global `\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\value{tocdepth}=\parttocdepth}% <- only parts in TOC
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\part{Foo}
\chapter{Intro}
\lipsum[66]
\section{Foo}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{image-a}
\label{fig:a}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[66]
\subsection{Bar}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While it's clear that `\value{...}=` works I believe `\setcounter` is more consistent `LaTeX` style. (+1 anyway!!)